# How do I execute javascript in a dynamically-added User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, updatepanel

I have a GridView of thumbnail photos within an UpdatePanel, with clickable icons in each row which each load a User Control containing a small Google Map into the relevant row. The idea is that the user can geotag (by clicking on the map) any photo in the GridView.

In the map User Control, there is some Javascript initialising the map:

```
function initializeMap() {
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('Map'), {size: new
GSize(336, 200)});
        // set the map controls, set the centre, etc.
    }
}
```

Problem is: I don't know how to call the `initializeMap()` method. Because it's dynamically added to the page, any attempt to link it to the calling button by `"onClientClick=initializeMap()"` for example, gives a JS error, saying the method isn't defined.

I've tried

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "initializeMap", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Here'); initializeMap();</script>");
```

but I don't think I'm on the right track with that one either.

Comment: Is the whole of the user control wrapped in an Update Panel?

Comment: Yes, the whole GridView is wrapped in the UpdatePanel, and the User Control gets added to a row of that GridView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx) to emit your javascript where there is an UpdatePanel involved like so:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "initializeMap", "initializeMap();", true);
```

Comment: Thanks Naaem, that's what I ended up doing.